# Envoy proxy forward to https endpoint: facing protocol error

Tags: amazon-web-services, envoyproxy

I'm trying to do this one: call public.com/api/v1/{proxy} to envoy proxy behind an ingress proxy. Envoy proxy will forward traffic to https private endpoint inside my VPC with diffrent path: [https://private.com/internal/{proxy}](https://private.com/internal/%7Bproxy%7D).

But I'm still facing the issue

> upstream reset: reset reason: connection termination, transport failure reason:

I even tried with public https endpoint but it's still the same.

Below is my configuration:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address:
      protocol: TCP
      address: 0.0.0.0
      port_value: 9901
static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener
      address:
        socket_address:
          address: 0.0.0.0
          port_value: 10000
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
          - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
            typed_config: 
              '@type': "type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager"
              stat_prefix: http_proxy
              access_log:
                - name: envoy.access_loggers.stdout
                  typed_config:
                    "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.access_loggers.stream.v3.StdoutAccessLog
              route_config: 
                name: all
                virtual_hosts:
                  - name: local_service
                    domains: 
                      - '*'
                    routes:
                      - match: { prefix: "/api/v1"}
                        route:
                          prefix_rewrite: "/internal/"
                          cluster: allbackend_cluster
              http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
  clusters:
    - name: allbackend_cluster
      connect_timeout: 1s
      type: strict_dns
      lb_policy: round_robin
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: allbackend_cluster
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
            - endpoint:
                address:
                  socket_address:
                    address: private.com
                    port_value: 443
      transport_socket:
        name: envoy.transport_sockets.tls
        typed_config:
          "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.transport_sockets.tls.v3.UpstreamTlsContext
          common_tls_context:
            validation_context:
              trusted_ca: {filename: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need to add certificates information for envoy

```
tls_context:
          common_tls_context:
            tls_certificates:
              - certificate_chain:
                  filename: "/etc/ssl/certs/https.crt"
                private_key:
                  filename: "/etc/ssl/certs/key.pem"
```

And also add trust the certificate used by cluster.

```
tls_context:
      common_tls_context:
          validation_context:
            trusted_ca:
              filename: "/etc/ssl/certs/cluster.crt"
```

Comment: I mean forwarding to third party https endpoint, so I don't have those keys

Comment: The keys for envoy you can generate using OpenSSL. Even in case of third party https endpoint, they should have a certificate publicly available

Comment: Oh I see, I will check for it. Thanks

Comment: I editted my question. Seems like add only tls_context does not work